# Open Source Scripting Languages that work well with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, python, sql-server, ruby, node.js

I have been using PHP for a number of years now and have found it to be (relatively) well documented, easy to work with, to setup and to use.

One of its main advantages is its capablility of working, without many modifications, similarly on a Windows or *nix platforms.

It also has good support for connecting to Microsoft SQL Servers, in particular 2005 + 2008 through the [mssql](http://php.net/mssql) module + ntwdblib.dll or [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/).

That being said, the more time I spend developing PHP, the more I feel the need to pick up another scripting language to broaden my skill set and to develop better web-based applications.

Because of this I've spent some time exploring alternative scripting languages in an effort to evaluate their suitability.

At present the biggest hurdle I have come accross is support provided by recent versions of the Open Source scripting languages, specifically: **Python 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.2, Node 0.5.7** for the Windows OS (**WinXP** in my case) and **Microsoft SQL Server (2005 + 2008)**.

My existing working environ necessitates the requirement for connecting to a MSSQL database.

I'm looking for answers from developers who have experience working with either Python, Ruby or Node.js and using them to interacting with a MS SQL Server.

What would be your recommended Open Source scripting language which has good support for MS SQL Server.

Ideas welcome.

-P.

Comment: I'm currently working with rails 3.0.9 and MS SQL Server. No major issues so far :) however MS SQL DB is used only for reading data from it.

Comment: @BohdanPohorilets is that to say your yet to get a full CRUD system together?

Comment: Thanks for the good work of metaskill Ruby has now excellent support for Microsoft SQL Server even in the Azure version with TinyTDS. I am using it accessing our legacy production system from RoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Ruby and Python should be able to connect to MS SQL databases.

Python libraries:

- [PyTDS](http://www.pytds.com/)
- [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/)

Ruby libraries:

- [TinyTDS](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) - doesn't seem to be DBI compliant, but there is an ActiveRecord adapter.

Comment: Documentation for the Python libraries don't seem to explicitly mention support for Python 3.2.x - I had no luck with pymssql when I tried it and discovered PyTDS requires payment to unlock restrictions.

Comment: You could try contacting the author about 3.2 support. The restrictions don't look like they're a problem for playing around with the library or developing a prototype, and $18 (or less) per core is, in software licence terms, peanuts. (SQL Server costs $7000 per CPU, or $900 plus $164/client.)

Comment: If you only need your application to run on Windows servers, you could also try [PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/).

Comment: PyODBC for Python 3.x appears to still be in beta development but I'll keep an eye on it. Appreciate the information on PyTDS.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord has support for mssql, using the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem.

Comment: AR queries don't have a DISTINCT keyword so sometimes you have to filter results to have only unique values